# How to calculate number of Saturday's Sunday's (Business Days) in a month in AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I tried the below logic in calculated fields of QuickSight analyses section but sometimes it fails.

```
WeekdayStart = extract('WD',${FromDate})
WeekdayEnd   = extract('WD',${ToDate})
TotalWeeks   = dateDiff(${FromDate},${ToDate},'WK')

Total weekdays =   ifelse(
    WeekdayStart > WeekdayEnd, abs(WeekdayStart-7)+(TotalWeeks*5)+(WeekdayEnd-1),
    WeekdayEnd = 7, abs(WeekdayStart-7)+((TotalWeeks-1)*5)+(WeekdayEnd-2),
    abs(WeekdayStart-7)+((TotalWeeks-1)*5)+(WeekdayEnd-1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a little differently. First, know what day of the week the event was, eg day =

```
extract("WD", time)
```

Then, create a unique day reference for each metric, eg, ts_day =

```
extract("YYYY",time) * 10000 + extract("MM",time) * 100 + extract("DD",time)
```

Then, count the days that have metrics, over the period being investigated eg work_days =

```
distinct_countIf(ts_day, day = 1 OR day = 7)
```

It's a bit unclear form your examples how you are using the date parameters. It looks like as both a filter range and also to define the "work days" for a week. And you seem to be treating Sat and Sun as business days not weekends?

If the work days change that much, you could use, eg work_days =

```
distinct_countIf(ts_day, 
    day >= extract("WD", ${FromDate}
       AND 
    day <= extract("WD", ${ToDate})
```

One caveat: this relies on at least ONE metric per workday to work. In practice it works well, but might need a "heartbeat" metric each day for accuracy if you have low volumes of data.